# How to remove duplicate values from variable in xml or xslt

Tags: xml, xslt

I am trying to find the value for metric tag and storing its value in incrementalprop variable .
when i am executing this code i am getting all the values of metric but i only want the unique value to be added in variable incrementalprop seperated by | , so for it i have used not contains if value doesnt contain metric value then
add in variable

<xsl:param name="incrementalprop">
<xsl:for-each select="//*:VIP/*:VIP_LIST/*:VIP_LINES">

```
    <xsl:choose>
    
  <xsl:when test="string-length(./*:Metric) >0 and not(contains(incrementalprop,./*:Metric))">
    <xsl:value-of select="./*:Metric"/>
    <xsl:text>|</xsl:text>
  </xsl:when>
  <xsl:otherwise>
    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
  </xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>

    </xsl:for-each>

    
    </xsl:param>
```

Output :-   HOSTED NAMED CENTER|HOSTED NAMED CENTER|HOSTED NAMED CENTER|HOSTED NAMED CENTER|DATA USER|DATA USER|DUMMY USER|UNKOWNN USER|

expected:- HOSTED NAMED CENTER|DATA USER|DUMMY USER|UNKOWNN USER

```
Sample Input :-
<VIP id="7273236vvvsd632">
    <client id=""/>
    <VIP_LIST>
        <VIP_LINES id="A">
            <Metric>HOSTED NAMED CENTER</Metric>
            <quantity>92</quantity>
            <phoneCountryCode xsi:nil="true"/>
            <phoneNumber xsi:nil="true"/>
        </VIP_LINES>
        <VIP_LINES id="B">
            <Metric>HOSTED NAMED CENTER</Metric>
            <quantity>92</quantity>
            <phoneCountryCode xsi:nil="true"/>
            <phoneNumber xsi:nil="true"/>
        </VIP_LINES>
        <VIP_LINES id="C">
            <Metric>DATA USER</Metric>
            <quantity>92</quantity>
            <phoneCountryCode xsi:nil="true"/>
            <phoneNumber xsi:nil="true"/>
        </VIP_LINES>
        <VIP_LINES id="D">
            <Metric>UNKOWNN USER</Metric>
            <quantity>92</quantity>
            <phoneCountryCode xsi:nil="true"/>
            <phoneNumber xsi:nil="true"/>
        </VIP_LINES>
        <VIP_LINES id="D">
            <Metric>DUMMY USER</Metric>
            <quantity>92</quantity>
            <phoneCountryCode xsi:nil="true"/>
            <phoneNumber xsi:nil="true"/>
        </VIP_LINES>
        <VIP_LINES id="D">
            <Metric>DATA USER</Metric>
            <quantity>92</quantity>
            <phoneCountryCode xsi:nil="true"/>
            <phoneNumber xsi:nil="true"/>
        </VIP_LINES>
        <VIP_LINES id="D">
            <Metric>HOSTED NAMED CENTER</Metric>
            <quantity>92</quantity>
            <phoneCountryCode xsi:nil="true"/>
            <phoneNumber xsi:nil="true"/>
        </VIP_LINES>
        ....
        ....
        ...
        ...
    </VIP_LIST>... ... .. 

</VIP>
```

Comment: Please post a [mcve] and state which XSLT processor you will be using.

Comment: added sample input above ... have multiple VIP_LIST and VIP_LINES

Answer (score 0):

With `*:VIP_LINES` I assume you have XSLT 2 or 3 so you can simply do

```
<xsl:param name="incrementalprop" select="string-join(distinct-values(//*:VIP_LINES/*:Metric), '|')"/>
```

Comment: In case of XSLT 1.0 ?